# How do you multiply by 10 using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a problem that can be equaled to the problem of multiplying by ten a number. The first approach would be:

```
   perl -pi -e 's/(\d+)/\1 0/g' myfile.txt
```

but this introduces an extra space and I can not put **\10** because such group does not exist.
   My solution was this workaround

```
   perl -pi -e 's/(\d+)/\1\l0/g' myfile.txt
```

to *lower case* 0 but I'm sure there is a proper way that I'm not aware of.

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are supposed to use the `$1` form instead of `\1` in substitutions.  This is in fact one of the reasons why:  with the variable form, you can say `${1}0`.

Answer (score 5):

Don’t use the `\1` notation on the RHS of a substitution.  Use `$1`.

There is, in general, an ambiguity issue between backrefs and octal notation. Or was. This is now solved.

In recent versions of Perl, when you need to unambiguously mean a backreference, you can use `\g{1}`, and when you need to unambiguously mean an octal number, you can use `\o{1}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `/e` modifier:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(\d+)/$1 * 10/ge' myfile.txt
```

See also [Warning on \1 Instead of $1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5C1-Instead-of-%241)

Comment: I think OP was looking for "append one more 0 to a number" rather than /e

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand on eugene's answer just for a little more accuracy to include digits. Especially if you were to do something other than multiply by ten, like divide by half.

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?<!\d|\.)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\d|\.)/$1 * 10/ge' file.txt
```

Also here is the version to ignore colors in hex format or percentages. Handy if you're modifying css.

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?<!#|\d|\.)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!%|\d|\.)/$1 * 10/ge' file.txt
```